# Terminal does not accept any input when ask for a password

Tags: command-line

As you know for trying to install softwares,terminal ask us for a password!but every time i trying to install software with sudo apt-get install command,my terminal ask me for a password,but when i typed it,it does not appear in terminal & terminal does not have any reaction to my typing!when i close terminal and start it again every thing is ok until i do same command for installing.

Answer (score 0):

That's a security feature. If you type your password and press enter, you'll be able to install the software.

Answer (score 0):

It won't show up when you type and nor will it move, you must type your password and press enter. If still doesn't work try copy-pasting because you be doing typos.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

For security reasons, whenever you type passwords in the terminal, they are *not* echoed back. This (presumably) is done so that someone looking cannot guess the password's length.

So, your passwords **are** being typed, it's just that you can't see them. Just type the password and hit Enter.

P.S. This confused me when *I* was a beginner, too.